# Group output in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to output something like this:

```
<div class="scrollable"><div class="items">
    <div><img src="1" alt=""/><img src="2" alt=""/><img src="3" alt=""/></div>
    <div><img src="4" alt=""/><img src="5" alt=""/><img src="6" alt=""/></div>
    <div><img src="7" alt=""/><img src="8" alt=""/><img src="9" alt=""/></div>
</div></div>
```

from array like ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']. How I can do it, given the fact, that array is dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `divisibleby` built-in filter.

```
<div>
{% for item in items %}
<img src="{{item}}" />
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}
    </div> <div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: If an answer answers your question, you might want to mark it as accepted by clicking the tick below the answer's up/down- vote arrows.

Comment: I know, but orange box with "You can accept an answer in 1 minute" appears :)